# How to create a limit query in sequelize?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a limit in my query which is supposed to look like this:
 `/api/hotels?featured=1&limit=2`

When I try and execute via postman and I get this message:

"message": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2'' at line 1",

And I can see that the server returns this:

> Executing (default): SELECT id, name, type, city, address, distance,
> photos, title, desc, rating, rooms, cheapestPrice, featured,
> createdAt, updatedAt FROM hotels AS hotels WHERE hotels.featured = '1'
> AND hotels.limit = '2' LIMIT '2';

My controller looks like this:

```
//GET ALL
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { min, max, ...others } = req.query;

    const hotels = await Hotel.findAll({
      where: {
        ...others,
      },
      limit: req.query.limit,
    });

    res.status(200).json(hotels);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

And my Model looks like this:

```
const Hotel = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Hotel = sequelize.define("hotels", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    type: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    city: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    address: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    distance: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    photos: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    desc: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      min: 0,
      max: 4,
    },
    rooms: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      allowNull: true,
    },
    cheapestPrice: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    featured: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      default: false,
    },
  });
  return Hotel;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

limit should be in number and not string; can you try the below
please note that this code is not tested `Number(req.query.limit)`

```
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { min, max,limit, ...others } = req.query;

    const hotels = await Hotel.findAll({
      where: {
        ...others,
      },
      limit: Number(limit),
    });

    res.status(200).json(hotels);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: When I try that, postman returns: 
"message": "Unknown column 'hotels.limit' in 'where clause'", 

And it looks like the server returns same error as mentioned above :/

Comment: yes because you need to remove limit from req.query

Comment: can you try the edited code now?

Comment: Yeah I tried it and it works perfectly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: nice remember to validate your limit value before using it directly might give you undefined if its not in the field and thats is another error

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction for doing that? 
Sequelize is brand new to me.

Comment: const parsedLimit = limit ? Number(limit) : 2;//your default value